# How can I vertically center text in a dynamically height div?

Tags: html, css, centering

```
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;">
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I vertically center the h1 tag inside of the div tag, no matter how tall the div element is? i.e. If the user changes his browser height, I want the h1 to vertically align in the center, according to the new height.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's an excellent article on the subject:  http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The best solution I've ever encountered is to make use of the `display` property and set the wrapper element as a `table` to allow the usage of `vertical-align:middle` on the element to be centered:

**See this** [working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/JrhQh/)!

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {width: 100%; height: 100%;}   /* this is just to "view" the div height...*/

div {
    position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;
    display: table;
}
h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

---

## TESTED ON

**Windows XP Profissional versão 2002 Service Pack 3**

- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 3.6.16
- Safari 5.1.2
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m

**Windows 7 Home Edition Service Pack 1**

- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.164211C
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 12.0
- Safari 5.1.4
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m

**Linux Ubuntu 12.04**

- Firefox 12.0
- Chromium 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux)

Comment: This won't work in IE7 and lower. But if that's not a concern - this  is the best solution. +1

Comment: This is an offline Kiosk so the app will only be run in Firefox.  This solution worked great in my case. +1

Comment: I think this is a good solution for dynamic height as well as static height container, works well.

Comment: See a BETTER answer for IE10+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60909392/8804293

Answer (score 19):

The answer I find the least obtrusive and least confusing requires inserting a `<span>` tag before the `<h1>` element: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/axRxE/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span></span><h1>Text</h1>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div { text-align: center; /* horizontally center */ }
div span {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
div h1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }​
```

Expanding this technique to vertically-align to the browser-height: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/axRxE/1/

Comment: Thanks for that nice workaround! I wrote a fallback for non capable browsers [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axRxE/2/)

Comment: The whitespace you added between your `<span>` and `<h1>` tags throws off the vertical-alignment.

Comment: Nothing I found worked. This one is simply awesome, thanks man!

Comment: This will be more simple by `:before` pseudo-element. http://jsfiddle.net/6kk8yyxk/1/

Answer (score 7):

I have the easiest 3 lines of css which are going to blow your mind and you will be thinking "Why didn't I think of this initially". Use this on the element you would like to be positioned vertically centered and the parent container just add a height of 100%.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

The position can be either relative, absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 7):

In 2012, the accepted answer was the correct/best option.

Flash forward 8 years, and [flex boxes are supported by every mainstream browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (IE10+):

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;  /* To also center horizontally, change to `rows` or remove */
```

*Note: If you care about IE10, you need to include `-ms-` prefix versions, per my hyperlink above.*

Comment: Yeah, I too prefer flex over `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(50%)` or tables

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/xQBbQ/

```
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;">
        <h1 style="text-align:center; height:20px; position:relative; top:50%; margin-top:-10px;">Text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That will fail for long texts that reach two or more lines, see [this simulation](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/xQBbQ/1/) with a `<br/>` to force the second line!

Comment: @Zuul the OP didn't state how long will be the text. Anyways the idea is to set the height of `<h1>` and give a negative margin of half of that

Comment: Just pointing out a "yet to come" problem! You continue to be right, plus, here's a +1 just to prove it!

Answer (score 2):

There's a **cross (desktop) browser solution** to do this with CSS2 + CSS3 and without any Javascript.

**Works in**

- IE5+
- Gecko's (Mozilla, Firefox, Netscape 7)
- Opera 7+
- Konqueror 3+
- Webkit Browsers (Safari, Google Chrome)
- and a lot more (Mobile browsers not tested)

**Documentation: Vertical Centering in CSS** Definitive Solution with Unknown Height:
 http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html
**Clean jsFiddle Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/WYgsP/

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerBox">
    <div class="helper">
        <div class="boxWithUnknownHeight">
            any text<br>
            any height<br>
            any content, for example generated from DB<br>
            everything is vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.outerBox {
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
    #position: relative; /* ie hack */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.helper {
    #position: absolute; /* ie hack */
    #top: 50%; /* ie hack */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.boxWithUnknownHeight {
    #position: relative; /* ie hack */
    #top: -50%;
    border: 1px solid green
}​
```

---

It works, even if i add text and line-breaks through Firebug etc.
*To keep your CSS clean from invalid CSS-Hacks, I'll recommend you to use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) for it and create a separate CSS with the browser specific Code.*

How vertical centering with unknown height exactly works and why: [**Detailed description**](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

---

**Other solutions** with `display: table` and or `display: table-cell` and or absolute positioning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/best-practice-vertical-align-center-content-on-div).

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
.object {
    background-color: #666666;
    height: 350px;
    width: 600px;
}
.verticalCenter {
    width:600px;
    height:350px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-175px 0 0 -300px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="verticalCenter">
        <div class="object">cetnered</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You must set height and width in .verticalCenter class the same as of your object (div, flash, image, text) that is to be centered. And margins must be half of these height and width.

I don't think there is solution if you change that object dynamically. Unless, maybe with javascripts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple solution.  It's mostly based on setting `display:table-cell` and choosing a vertical alignment like middle.

HTML:

```
<div id="vertical">
    <p>this text is vertically centered.  It's long enough to wrap, and should work for any size chunk of content.</p>
    <p>Heck, it even works with multiple items in the middle.</p>
</div>​​
```

CSS:

```
#vertical {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
}​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Re3E/1/

Comment: True, it's not going to work for IE6 or 7.  I'm sure a simple JS solution exists for IE7.  Life's too short to be worried over IE6.

Comment: This site show a solution for both, which is a mix of our methods (yours needs a tweak with a container being centered instead of the raw contents): http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/centervertically.html

Answer (score 1):

I use tables for everything.  I personally do not enjoy using`display: table` or anything like that when there is something that already exists.

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Whatever you want vertically and horizontally centered -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using this same method, you can do something like this for your case:

```
<div id="container-div" style="position: relative">
    <div id="random-content-that-changes-container-height-and-width" style="height: 600px; width: 400px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- Whatever you want vertically and horizontally centered -->
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: people worry about semantic classes ( https://www.impressivewebs.com/avoid-nonsemantic-classes/ ) and you're using table elements for layout?

Comment: Nevermind, obviously an old commen,t but if you still are, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/84986/2848941

Comment: Only answer that worked for me even in 2022!

Answer (score -2):

From my point of view, `div`is not appropriate choice in this case. My suggestion is go for `table` and `vertical-align` style on it's `td`s.

Comment: Don't use a table for non-tabular data.

Comment: Tables not acceptable semantically to anything but tabular data.

Comment: It's more reliable solution for designing cross browser.

Comment: Nope. For page structure it's even more evil. Forget about tables :)

Comment: Good point for today. I didn't think about that. Thanks guys.