# How to vertically align into the center of the content of a div with defined width/height?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

What would be the correct method to vertically center any content in a defined width/height `div`.

In the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/) there are two contents with different heights, what is the best way to center vertically both using the class `.content` . (and it works for every browser and without the solution of `table-cell`)

Have some solutions on mind, but would like to know other ideas, one is using `position:absolute; top:0; bottom: 0;` and `margin auto`.

Comment: Your questions should be fully self-contained. Otherwise, when the URL goes dead, it's useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how can i vertically center text in a dynamically high div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939288/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-in-a-dynamically-high-div)

Comment: Probably , but that time didn't have the solution i want... this offers more options

Comment: **tl;dr in 2020**: `display: flex; align-items: center;`. If you *don't* want it to be horizontally centered as well, add `flex-direction: column;`.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I have researched this a little and from what I have found you have four options:

### Version 1: Parent div with display as table-cell

If you do not mind using the `display:table-cell` on your parent div, you can use of the following options:

```
.area{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/8/)

---

### Version 2: Parent div with display block and content display table-cell

```
.area{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}

.content {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;    
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/17/)

---

### Version 3: Parent div floating and content div as display table-cell

```
.area{
    background: red;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/16/)

---

### Version 4: Parent div position relative with content position absolute

The only problem that I have had with this version is that it seems you will have to create the css for every specific implementation. The reason for this is the content div needs to have the set height that your text will fill and the margin-top will be figured off of that. This issue can be seen in the demo. You can get it to work for every scenario manually by changing the height % of your content div and multiplying it by -.5 to get your margin-top value.

```
.area{
    position:relative; 
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:red;
    margin:10px;
}

.content { 
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; 
    height:50%; 
    width:100px;
    margin-top:-25%;
    text-align:center;
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/22/)

Comment: @JoshMein : Few more solutions: [how can i vertically center text in a dynamically high div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939288/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-in-a-dynamically-high-div)

Comment: Version 2 is what I'm looking for, however the content doesn't get centered vertically. Does it matter what `area` is contained in, or what `content` contents is?

Answer (score 94):

This could also be done using `display: flex` with only a few lines of code. Here is an example:

```
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s1cnpxcm/)

Comment: @nihiser Only if you also want to center it horizontally also, or if you would have set `flex-direction: column`

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a parent div with fixed or absolute position

Answer (score 39):

I found this solution in this [article](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

```
.parent-element {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It work like a charm if the height of element is not fixed.

Comment: JFYI, I found the same article and used that approach. I had to change position to absolute for it to work in Chrome.

Comment: @JackA. works with `position: relative` in chrome 62. Not sure how far back that goes.

Comment: Works as advertised.  Changing the size of the content being centered automagically re-centered too.

Answer (score -1):

Simple trick to vertically center the content of the div is to set the line height to the same as height:

```
<div>this is some line of text!</div>
div {
width: 400px
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

but this is works only for one line of text!

Best approach is with div as container and a span with the value in it:

```
.cont {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table;
}

.val {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

    <div class="cont">
      <span class="val">CZECH REPUBLIC, 24532 PRAGUE, Sesame Street 123</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -4):

I would say to add a paragraph with a period in it
and style it like so:

```
<p class="center">.</p>

<style>
.center {font-size: 0px; margin-bottom: anyPercentage%;}
</style>
```

You may need to toy around with the percentages to get it right

Comment: You may use this inside a <div>. Margin-Bottom assumes you placed it first in your div component.

Comment: Not what I would call `responsive` since it will be pretty hardcoded. Maybe `calc()` could have helped here, but saying `anyPercentage%` is not the solution at all here.

Answer (score -9):

margin: all_four_margin

by providing 50% to all_four_margin will place the element at the center

`style="margin: 50%"`

you can apply it for following too

margin: top right bottom left

margin: top right&left bottom

margin: top&bottom right&left

by giving appropriate % we get the element wherever we want.

Comment: please clarify, your wording seems a bit all over the place and disjointed.

Comment: Unclear answer with bad phrasing and limited to list the possible values for `margin`.