# Float div vertical align div

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practice vertical-align center content on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/best-practice-vertical-align-center-content-on-div)

How can I vertical align center .content for the both squares using same CSS.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/9/)

Thanks

Comment: You asked the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/best-practice-vertical-align-center-content-on-div

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected result...

Comment: I want to vertical-align .content , but since I add float: left, stop working

Comment: Your questions should be fully self-contained.  Otherwise, when the URL goes dead, it's useless.  And secondly, please don't post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/best-practice-vertical-align-center-content-on-div) multiple times.

Comment: I want to delete.. unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution -> http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/12/.

You need to add `display: table-cell;` to the inner .content, set *their* vertical-align to middle (`vertical-align: middle;`) and give them the same `height` and `width` of their parent .area (100% width and height unfortunately don't work here, so when you alter the `.area`'s height and width, you also have to do it for the .content div).

Answer (score 0):

`style='vertical-align:middle'` ..

Comment: Check the example, it works without FLOAT, but want to know how to do it with Float.

Comment: mm.. margin-top? check it out

Comment: But then is not a general css to apply to the div.content

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `display table-cell` to the wrong elements. You have to wrap them in a container, and apply `display: table cell` to that container. Check my example -> http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/10/

Comment: Thanks , but I want to the div.content to be vertically center not the red squares.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues Ain't the red squares are .content? um... may be you want to review your question :-/

Comment: .content for the both squares --> its says in the question vertical align .content for the both squares

Answer (score 0):

When u got a fixed height i would just add a `line-height: 100px;` and remove your `vertical-align` and `display`

[jsfiddle modification](http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/14/)