# How to vertically center my container div

Tags: html, css

I am able to center my elements horizontally, but not vertically. I found couple of questions on stackoverflow regarding the same issue but the suggestions in those didn't work for some reason. Any suggestions? This is what I am going for: http://i62.tinypic.com/n4gzcw.png

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <style>

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.datetime {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.left img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
}

.mid {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.right {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.right img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
}

.stadium {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;    
}
</style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="datetime">26 August 2014<br />12:00pm</div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left"><img src="http://dejaniskra.comze.com/ManchesterUnitedUpcomingFixture/logos/mkdons.png" /></div>
        <div class="mid">MK Dons vs Manchester United</div>
        <div class="right"><img src="http://dejaniskra.comze.com/ManchesterUnitedUpcomingFixture/logos/manchesterunited.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stadium">Stadium:mk - Milton Keynes</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your content with .container-inner and add styles:

```
.container-inner{
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

you can find the working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkfdxm13/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a partial CSS layout and then attempting to adapt it to another strategy can be fraught with problems. My suggestion would be to create a clean set of html wrappers with only background colours and work on employing one of the solutions that you've found, for example [How to verticaly align into the center of the content of a div with defined width/height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/best-practice-vertical-align-center-content-on-div). Once you have a working layout then you can move your content in.
If you come across a problem that you can't solve then you can post a specific CSS question and the answers will probably be a lot more forthcoming.