# Vertically Centering Text in Jumbotron - Height won't inheirit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the text in the `.jumbotron` div to be pushed down half way between the div, instead of hovering towards the top. I am opting to use `padding-top: 50%`. Instead, it's centering halfway down the entire page, not halfway down the div. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvegtyvo/

The height of the div is determined by the viewport size, so it is not a definite number. I set the height in `#jumbotron-header` to be inherited from the parent `.jumbotron`, but it's ignoring the inherited height and still centering 50% down the entire page.

Does anyone have any idea why the height is not being inherited? Does it have to do with using vh as the height instead of a solid number?

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center img-responsive" id="jumbotron">
    <div id="jumbotron-header">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url(images/jumbo.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;

}

#jumbotron-header{
    height: inherit;
    padding-top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: try vertical-align: middle

also check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/how-to-verticaly-align-into-the-center-of-the-content-of-a-div-with-defined-widt

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/vertically-center-with-bootstrap/

Comment: thanks calvin. i would have loved to use vertical-align: middle, but it didn't seem to work when I initially tried it out

Comment: thanks for the resources, but id also like to figure out why the inherit property is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i think use of `padding` value in `%` makes the `jumborton header` to go `50%` down if you see in the below snippet that when removing `padding` of `.jumborton` and adding the `padding` value in `px` in `#jumborton-header` it makes the text to be in center and `height` is also `inherit`.

If you want to see than see the below snippet

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: url(images/jumbo.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0!important;
}
#jumbotron-header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: inherit;
  padding-top: 50px;  
  padding-bottom: 50px;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron text-center img-responsive">
  <div id="jumbotron-header">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give `padding-top` in `%`, it will calculate according to its **width**, instead of its height. That's why it did not become vertically center. Instead of padding, you can use following  for the vertical alignment of the inner div.

**display:table** for outer div.

Then **display:table-cell** and **vertical-align:middle** for inner div

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url(images/jumbo.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;

    display: table;

}

#jumbotron-header{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```