# How to center vertically a h1 in middle of a div container?

Tags: html, css

as said in the title all i need is centering vertically a title h1 in the middle of a div.

this is a very simple code :

```
<div class="container">
<h1> title in multiple lines, so i can't use line-height, i must use something else </h1>
```

```
.container{
width:500px;
height:180px;
background-color:red;
text-align:center;
}

h1{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This is a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/dqjb6kqr/1/)

After using display table, the text is nicely centered vertically, thank you All. Now i'm facing a new problem; (look at the jsffidle [here please](http://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/dqjb6kqr/10/)
What i want is "text 1" and "text 2" will be displayed side by side, and every small blue div goes under the two red divs in the middle of every red div.. any help please ?

Comment: This definetely is a duplicate.

Comment: Hi @JustusRomijn here i get great answer (flex)

Comment: @Sushi yes, but I could just mark one other question as the duplication. There are ton's of questions regarding vertical centering on SO already. A quick google gives me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/how-to-verticaly-align-into-the-center-of-the-content-of-a-div-with-defined-widt

Comment: hello @JustusRomijn i just added an update in my question please take a look i'm really trying to make it work but it doesn't

Comment: @Sushi create another question then. It is no longer related to your original question. We're just trying to keep SO organized (as far as that is possible...)

Comment: Thank you justus you're right

Answer (score 9):

### Solution #1

Add `display:table;` to container and `display:table-cell;` to h1

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    display:table; /* <---- */
}

h1{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell; /* <--- */
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dqjb6kqr/2/)

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
h1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> title in multiple lines, so i can't use line-height, i must use something else </h1>
</div>
```

### Solution #2 : Flexbox

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dqjb6kqr/3/)

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> title in multiple lines, so i can't use line-height, i must use something else </h1>
</div>
```

### Solution #3 - Transforms

```
h1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dqjb6kqr/5/)

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> title in multiple lines, so i can't use line-height, i must use something else </h1>
</div>
```

### Solution #4 Add a Pseudo element with 100% height

```
.container:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -4px; /* to counter inline-block whitespace */
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dqjb6kqr/6/)

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
  /* to counter inline-block whitespace */
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> title in multiple lines, so i can't use line-height, i must use something else </h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the 2 solutions i think i'm gonna use flex thank you again

Comment: @Danield your flexbox solution does not work with small text! Add `width:100%;` to `h1` to allow small text.