# Line-height and dynamic height of div

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how can I set line-height to be always equal to height of the container div - in order to center the element inside of the container in the middle of the height of the container.

Lets say I have a following:

```
<div style="height:12%">
<i style="line-height:??"></i>
</div>
```

How can I set line height, so that it changes with the changes when the height of the container div changes?

Thanks 
uksz

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to acheive here. Could you give a little more information? line-height is always relative to the font as this is most of the time what is needed. Are you trying to center it?

Comment: @DanielCasserly, yes, thats exactly what I am trying to do. Editing post in a moment.

Comment: @uksz - being that you're trying to vertically center here - you could try one of the methods for centering within a div with dynamic height  in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33362841/703717)

Answer (score 4):

You put another inline-level element on the same line with a height equal to 100% of the container. It's most common to use `display:inline-block;` here, but any inline-level element to which height applies, such as `inline-table`, `inline-flex` or a replaced inline element will work just as well.

e.g div:before { content:''; display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; }

```css
html, body { height: 900px; }

div { border:1px solid black; height: 12%; }

div:before { content:''; display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; }
```

```html
<div>
<i>My text</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The intuitive way would be to set the `line-height` to `100%`, but that actually just sets the line height to **100% size of the font**

Assuming you probably want to center your text, try this

```
.container {
     position:relative;
}
.center {
     position:absolute;
     top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
     margin: auto;
     /* for horiz left-align, try "margin: auto auto auto 0" */
}
```