# vertical align a selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vertical-alignment

I try since hours to vertical middle the selectpicker and I absolute don't get it...

https://jsfiddle.net/zukii/wyg8po3p/

how can i vertical align it to middle?

HTML

```
<h4 class="green">I am a Headline...</h4>
  <div class="border-left">
    <div class="mos-form-group">
      <div class="col_half">
        <label>Scelerisque ultricies elementum placerat sociis massa cras natoque dignissim dapibus lundium vel, eu arcu porttitor, adipiscing. In cursus. Natoque nunc et, elementum mattis etiam ac! Massa in natoque est scelerisque aliquet massa, sagittis diam? Proin? Urna? Sed urna! Cum elit, augue habitasse? Mauris et ut dignissim integer a! Nisi urna?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input col_half col_last">
        <select class="selectpicker" name="bkv_q1">
          <option>Nein</option>
          <option>Ja</option>
        </select><span class="input-group-addon ttbtn active"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968726/how-to-verticaly-align-into-the-center-of-the-content-of-a-div-with-defined-widt

Answer (score 0):

So basically `vertical-align` applies to inline elements so that I modified your css code here below If i got your question right

```
.mos-form-group > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: initial;
    margin-right: initial;
}
```

[Here is Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/wyg8po3p/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ;) I tried this in my Code but it don't work because I've got a Tooltip .. here is the complete Code: http://www.design-splash.de/middle/

Comment: @zukii have you tried adding `!important` to the style rules because they're overriding by the specific rules. I tried it in your website It's working. Let me know what you come up with?

Comment: display: flex; align-items: center;

Answer (score 0):

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
```

This works pretty fine for me.. Thanks 4 your help guys.. have a nice sunday