# Vertically center div with dynamic height and 100% width

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I vertically center text in a dynamically high div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939288/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-in-a-dynamically-high-div)

How to vertically center div with dynamic height and 100% width in browser window?

```
<div class="login-signup-page">
<div class="login-signup"></div>
</div>
```

where login-signup has 100% width and dynamic height

Comment: **Dublicate**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939288/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-in-a-dynamically-high-div/10939940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kolink is indeed correct, but it doesn't take much work. All it takes is some clever CSS and JavaScript (I used jQuery in my example below) to make it work.

```
<div class="login-signup-page">
<div class="login-signup">Sample Text</div>
</div>​

.login-signup-page {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:grey;
}

.login-signup {
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
​

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.login-signup').css('margin-top', -$('.login-signup').outerHeight() + 'px'); 
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kDYDf/)

Comment: Also, please be aware that if the content is longer than the window you might lose some of your content to to overflow.

Comment: You may want to consider `outerHeight()` instead of `height()`, to take into account padding and border.

Comment: May I ask what the reasoning is for multiplying the height by `-1` when you could just slap a `-` in front of it?

Comment: @Kolink, just a difference in the way we write and read ;) Both work, don't they?

Comment: I guess I just have an aversion to seeing two such operators side by side. Nothing wrong with `*-1`, of course, just personal preference. And two fewer bytes :p

Comment: @RyanKinal - Changed my code to reflect your wise advice...

Comment: @Kolink - Made an edit, and it's all for you.

Comment: Since it's of variable height, you may want to select a minimum top margin, so your content doesn't fall off the top of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: If you know the height, you can use fixed positioning, a `top:50%` and a `margin-top` equal to negative half the height. Short of that, you can use some basic JS to calculate what the `margin-top` should be based on the `offsetHeight`. If you are vertically centering in another element, rather than the window, you can do the same but with an absolute position provided the container is not static-positioned.

Comment: This user speaks the truth. Further, from personal experience, a set top margin of 50px to 150px usually looks far better than a vertically centered box. The reason being that, usually, the eye will scan from the top of the page down, so a large margin at the top will affect the user far more than a large margin at the bottom.

Comment: @RyanKinal - Very true. If you want to do it, it's possible, but in my opinion, not a very smart design choice.

Answer (score 0):

See the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HuDFD/5/) or go straight to the code below:

### HTML

```
<div class="login-signup-page">
<div class="login-signup"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
.login-signup-page {

 /* Position at top of page */
 position:fixed;
 top:0;

 /* Position halfway down page (in supporting browsers) */
 -moz-transform:translate(0, 50%);
 -webkit-transform:translate(0, 50%);
 -ms-transform:translate(0, 50%);
 -o-transform:translate(0, 50%);
 transform:translate(0, 50%);

 /* Prevent hidden content */
 height:100%;
 width:100%;

}

.login-signup {

 /* Prevent hidden content */
 max-height:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 overflow:auto;

 /* Position in center of page (in supporting browsers) */
 -moz-transform:translate(0, -50%);
 -webkit-transform:translate(0, -50%);
 -ms-transform:translate(0, -50%);
 -o-transform:translate(0, -50%);
 transform:translate(0, -50%);

}
```

***Note:** In browsers that don't support `translate()`, the content will appear at the top of the page (instead of being cut off, had `top:50%;` been used instead).*

Answer (score -2):

You'll need Javascript or jQuery to get the height of the element and the browser window, then calculate based on those numbers. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var signupHeight = $('.login-signup').height(); // height of your dynamic element
    var winHeight = $(window).height(); // height of the browser window
    $('.login-signup').css('margin-top',(winHeight - signupHeight) / 2); // subtract one height from the other, then divide by 2 so the top and bottom margins are equal
});
```