# Don't manage positioning (side-by-side)

Tags: html, css

I have following fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BFSH4/

As you see there are two issues:

1. The h1 and h2 aren't vertically aligned.
2. The nav and the content aren't horzontal alligned.

For the 1. I already tried margin and padding. No success...

The second one also isn't that easy the common ways of floating and using inline-block don't work...

What am I doing wrong?

I finally managed floating the header. The problem was that hgroup isn't a block element.
However even it worked after all I think it is better to use a real image for the enterprise name and slogan.

Now only the issue with the horizontal alignment fails.

I don't know why:
http://jsfiddle.net/BFSH4/2/

I can do what I want there is no way that they wan't to be side by side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for your first problem** ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939288/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-in-a-dynamically-high-div/10939940#10940314)):

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <span></span><img src="images/prototype.png" /><hgroup><h1>Prototype</h1><h2>SideBySide</h2></hgroup>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #8a2be2;
    /* text-align: center; */
}

.header span {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 160px;
    float: left; /* added, so the image will appear left to the text correctly */
}

.header hgroup {
    margin: 0;        
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This solution depends on [`display: inline-block`](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block)

**Solution for the second problem**:

```
.nav {
    width: 229px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BFSH4/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BFSH4/1/ Hi, I tried the methods mentioned in youre link but I don't know how I could verticaly align + horizontal align to the image. Combining both fails.... I don't know what you want to tell me about the second issue. What do the li's have to do with horizontal alignment of .nav and .content container???

Comment: Finally corrected my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/BFSH4/4/ Hope this works for you.