# Vertical Align inside <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div id="workAllocated">
    <h3>Work Allocated</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>  
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>  
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
div#contentarea.profile_edit div {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div#contentarea.profile_edit div.col_01 h3 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    margin: 0;
}
div#workAllocated p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

The result looks like this snapshot:

[image]

But I need it to looks like this:

[image]

The different is the vertical align of the text inside the `<p>` tags. It is aligned top-left inside the `<p>` container but it should be middle-left. I've tried some  [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051951/vertically-middle-align-of-the-text-in-p-tag)  as change the line-height and change the display to table-cell and then apply the vertical-align property, but none of them really work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you really want to use a table for this, as your example looks like tabular data.

Comment: [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding) or [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a height for your p's and then set the line height equal to that one.

Comment: Setting heights isn't safe generally. If text size is set to larger than you expect, some of it might get cut off.

Comment: Setting a font size as well helps.

Comment: @mario595, you're going to have difficulty finding a satisfactory CSS solution using P tags.  This looks like tabular data, and a table will have no problem with `vertical-align`, so I really think you should use a table.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. I was changing the line-height but I didn't set the height of the <p> so it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrEcx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div#workAllocated p {
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px 0;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="workAllocated">
    <h3>Work Allocated</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>  
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p> 
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>  
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>  
    <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a height to the p and adjust your line-height to it

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8xd7/2/)`.`

//EDIT// oops just saw the other anwser