# Center an HTML element with an unknown width to the middle of the screen

Tags: css, positioning

If I have a HTML element with an unknown width and height, how can I centre it to exactly the middle of the screen?

If it cannot be done with pure CSS, then javascript is OK.

Comment: Easy to implement CSS only solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939288/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-in-a-dynamically-high-div/10939940#10940314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may or may not fit your situation, depending on *how* the unkown width/height are being determined. If the *exact* dimensions are unkown, but they are set with *percentages*, then you can use this technique:

```
#content {
    background-color: khaki; /* demo purposes */  
    position: absolute;   
    height: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10%; /* half the height */   
    width: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15%; /* half the width */
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCP9e/) for an example. To summarize:

- **Con**: only applicable if the exact dimensions are unkown because they are specified in %.
- **Pro**: pure CSS solution.

Comment: but the OP said: "Center an HTML element **with an unknown width** to the middle of the screen"

Comment: I know, but it's not specified if only the **exact width** or *both the **exact and relative width*** are unkown. If someone stumbles on this question because he has a `%` width (and thus an **unkown exact width**) my answer may be of use.

Comment: I see your point but having struggled with similar issues I doubt that when he says that the width is unknown he means that it has a known width in %. Had that been the case he would have probably asked about vertical centering... still maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: thank you! This solution is way simpler than the one above. Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it through jquery..

```
$(function () {
    var element=$("#elementid")
    element.css("position","absolute");
    element.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    element.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + 

});
```

Comment: You probably can, but that would mean dealing a lot more with browser differences yourself...